# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StudentsController#new Couldn't find Student with 'id'=all

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i just started working with ruby
trying to create a online form
it started showing the above error
could anyone help me with this
my code students_controller.rb

```
 class StudentsController < ApplicationController
 def new
@student = Student.new
@students = Student.find(:all)
end

def create
@student = Student.new(student_params)
if @student.save
    redirect_to new_student_path
end
end
def student_params
allow = [:firstname, :lastname]
params.require(:student).permit(allow)

end

end
```

my code for new.html

```
Enter new student information 
<hr>
<%= form_for @student do |f| -%>
 Firstname: <%= f.text_field :firstname %><br /><br />
 Lastname:  <%= f.text_field :lastname %><br /><br />
<%= f.submit %>
<% end -%>
<hr>
Display all students' information
<% if !@students.blank? %>
<% for item in @students %>
   <%= item.firstname %> <%= item.lastname %> <br />
<% end %>
<% else %>
<% end %>
```

my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :students
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

`@students = Student.all`

instead of

`@students = Student.find(:all)`